# Is there a trick to use style in span with InnerHtml, with a variable style?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, innerhtml

I want to show a tag with a strange format, so I did this function to parse the tag and return HTML code to use it with InnerHtml, but the style don't work.
I'm with angular, and I'm asking if there is a trick to fix this ?

```js
    public getPlayerTag(tag: string) {
      let example= "$O$FF0I$FFFI$D4DI$333I";
      let tagArray = tag.split("$");
      // remove the 2 first element
      tagArray.shift();
      tagArray.shift();
      // create an array with the first 3 char and an other array with the rest
      let tagArray2 = tagArray.map(function(element) {
        return element.substring(0, 3);
      });
      let tagArray3 = tagArray.map(function(element) {
        return element.substring(3);
      });
      return tagArray2.map(function(element, index) {
        // return span with color in style
        return "<span style='color: #" + element + ";'>" + tagArray3[index] + "</span>";
      }).join("");
    }
```

```html
    <div [innerHtml]="getPlayerTag(player.tag)"></div>
```

And when I go to see the elements of the page I have this:

```html
    <div>
      <span>I</span>
      <span>I</span>
      <span>I</span>
      <span>I</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use innerHTML here, rather build the single parts in a function in angular (you are already doing this) and then use ngFor or something to display them. What is the desired output? Do you have an example? When looking at your function it's difficult to say what `element` is in your last line. Why is an element a color?

Comment: Yes the element is the 3 characters that define the color, for example 'FFF', so I parse this and add to the style, I will try to do a ngFor and set the style with ngStyle I think